# Can you use Magical Secrets to choose high level spells when multiclassing as a Bard?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, bard

Say you have a Wizard 7/Bard 9. You gain your 17th level and choose to gain the level in Bard (which grants you Magical Secrets). According to the Multiclass Spellcaster: Spell Slots per Spell Level table, you now have a single 9th level spell slot. Can the spells you choose from Magical Secrets be 9th level spells even though you can only cast up to 5th level Bard spells?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. Magical Secrets specifies that the spells you learn from it must be

> of a level you can cast, **as shown on the Bard table**, or a cantrip.

As a 10th-level Bard, you can only learn spells up to 5th level using Magical Secrets, even if you also have other levels in another spellcasting class.

Comment: It might be worth referencing the [multiclass spellcasting rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/customization-options#Spellcasting) that say you determine known/prepared spells as if single-classed in each class; you wouldn't be able to cast bard spells above 5th level normally (though you can use a higher-level slot to cast a bard spell you know), and the feature doesn't change that.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the relevant section. I wonder if you could delay your picking your spells for Additional Magical Secrets. *pensive look* :)

Answer (score 5):

To quote the Player's Handbook page 54 under the Bard Features:

> ### Magical Secrets
>
> By 10th level, you have plundered magical knowledge from a wide spectrum of disciplines. Choose two spells from any class, including this one. *A spell you choose must be of a level you can cast, as shown on the Bard table, or a cantrip.*

So that is the relevant portion. You can choose spells for which you have spell slots from your Bard levels alone.

Comment: The Spells Known and Prepared section (page 164 of the Player's Handbook) contradicts part of what you said. "You determine what spells you know and can prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed member of that class."

Comment: @Avilyn That is for classes who prepare spells. That means if you are a Wizard 5/Cleric 5 you cannot prepare Cleric spells in the spots you would prepare your Wizard spells, and Vice Versa. You can _cast_ a spell you have prepared as long as you have a spell slot for that spell. Upon reading the book though, I was wrong about my second point.

Comment: Actually I think that quote does matter. "You determine **what spells you know** […], as if you were a single-classed member of that class." That is the rule for spells known for all spellcasters.

Comment: *A spell you choose must be of a level you can cast, as shown on the Bard table* - if you can only cast 5th level Bard spells, you can only learn 5th level spells via Magical Secrets

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Indeed, I misread it at first but I see that now that you pointed it out. And reading what Adeptus said, I imagine that Additional Magical Secrets from the College of Lore is the same way. That does limit its possibilities, which is unfortunate. I haven't thought through the incorrect interpretation though, so it might be totally busted.