# What's the maximum amount of Constructs you can have active at one time?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, constructs

I'm on a bit of a Construct schtick right now, and my character is aiming specifically to make the most constructs possible. The roadmap is Lvl 13 College of Creation Bard/Lvl 3 Battle Smith Artificer, taking the Homunuculus Infusion and the Replicate Magic Item Infusion (Pot of Awakening). Is there anything that I'm missing? Are there any other avenues?

As a side note, the focus is on permanent constructs rather than temporary, but many temporary constructs can be a valid answer as well, and -accordingly edited due to helpful comments- let's assume they must be made by my character alone, and there's only 5 in-game days and 500 gp.

Comment: Do you consider constructs from magic items (not created by artificer infusion)? Afaik there is no limit on how many shrubs you can awaken with Pot of Awakening, so the maximum amount is potentially limitless

Comment: On a side note, the awakened shrub isn't a construct per se, but a plant

Comment: If there is a limted amount of time and resources, it would be good to state what the limits actually are. Otherwise, an arbitrarily large limit is functionally no limit.

Comment: If there's only a limited amount of time and resources, we need to know what those limits are if we are going to accurately answer your question. Voting to close for more details.

Comment: Edited for specificity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In practical terms, 32

Because this is not for a theoretical optimization puzzle, but for your actual player character, I'll answer this for your specific character. First, what is a number of minions you could practically amass?

From **Battle Smith Artificer 3**: 2 constructs

- **Infuse an Item** (level 2): will give you a maximum of two Infused Items. As you can have each of your infusions in one object only, the **Homunculus Servant** Infusion can be used with it to create **1 construct** (cost 100 gp)
- **Steel Defender** (level 3): allows you one defender at any one time, **1 construct**
- **Replicate Magic Item**: this does not do anything for you. (The *Pot of Awakening* creates plants, not constructs), **0 constructs**
- **Artificer spells**: none of the spells on your list up to spell level 2 creates a construct. The earliest is *tiny servant* at spell level 3, for which you would need to be an artificer 5. **0 constructs**.

From **College of Creation Bard 13**: 30 constructs

- **Animating Performance** (level 6): you can animate one Dancing Item, and at any time you can only have one of them active. It lasts for 1 hour. **1 construct**
- **Bard spell list**: this will give you access to *animate objects* (level 10, spell level 5). The spell requires concentration, and for up to 1 minute allows you to animate up to 10 tiny objects that count as constructs. It also is a good damage dealing spell. **10 constructs**
- **Magical Secrets** (level 10) lets you choose two spells from any list, at 10th level up to spell level 5. This opens up a huge space of spells.

  - You could for example (if the DM allows non-core spells, which is likely as Artificer is a non-core class) pick ***tiny servant***. This is a third level spell with a duration of 8 hours that creates a construct, and you are not limited to how many you create, other than by your spell slots. As a bard of 13th level, you have 10 slots of 3rd level or higher, so at most you could create 10 of them per long rest. If you still have all of these slots at the end of the day and cast with [unused spell slots at the end of a long rest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/198324/75095), then cast them again on the new day, you can double up on that for 20. If you save one 5th level slot for Animate Object, for 19. **19 constructs**.
  - Another option is *summon construct* but it only summons one construct for up to one hour, and is concentration, so it competes with your use of *animate objects*. The *create homunculus* (spell level 12, caster level 6) is not an option unless your DM allows you to delay the pick, because [rules as written , you cannot delay to pick](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/197327/can-you-wait-until-a-higher-level-to-make-a-magical-secrets-selection), and at 10th level only have access to level 5 spells. **1 construct** (but not while also using *animate objects*)

This would bring you to a grand total of **32 constructs** at peak, 2 of which would hang around all the time (1 homunculus servant, 1 steel defender).

#### Some considerations for your build and for minion management

Please consider that while constructs may be charming and fun initially, if you try to optimize your character solely for lots of them, that is unlikely to result in a well-rounded character. You will have to make trade-offs for this. For example, the Magical Secrets feature is very useful, and in my list, you burn both of your picks on just having more weakish minions, which adds little to your character. You already have homunculus minions, for example, so how much do you really benefit for having additional *tiny servants*? Would it make you play any differently? If you were not using it on even more constructs, you could pick other useful effects.

As [@MivaScott points out](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/207661/whats-the-maximum-amount-of-constructs-you-can-have-active-at-one-time/207669?noredirect=1#comment569247_207669), having more such construct minions also has diminishing returns. Many of these constructs require the owner's bonus action to actually do something; very few act on their own. Did you use your bonus action to create magic stones for the tiny servants? Too bad, now those tiny servants, are just going to stand/float around for the round. The steel defender is going to sit idle, like your Homunculus Servant. They may look like an impressive force, but they're just hit point sponges then.

Lots of minions also are not necessarily a fun play experience, because they are a hassle to manage. I have been playing a wizard that is able to create a whole zoo of minions (with *animate dead*, a familiar, a Shield Guardian, and a gaggle of elementals from *summon minor elementals* at times, and he also owns a *pot of awakening* and an *ebony fly*). I stopped using most of them, as it became too much of an administrative burden. For example, if you play on a virtual desktop, you have to move around all these pogs all the time, and at higher levels many of them contribute little to combat. See [here for helpful advise on how to manage your minions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/198561/75095).

Comment: I would also add that most of these "constructs" require the owner's bonus action to actually do something; very few minions act on their own. Did you use your bonus action to create magic stones for the tiny servants? Too bad, now those tiny servants, your animated dead and animated objects are just going to stand/float around for the round. The steel defender is going to sit idle. And your Homunculus Servant is twiddling their thumbs. They may look like an impressive force, but they're all just hit point sponges most of the time.

Comment: You can't have two homunculi at the same time. Each of your infusions can be in only one object at a time, and unless an infusion's description says otherwise,
you can't learn an infusion more than once. Homunculus Servant doesn't let you learn it twice.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym Thanks, I missed that and will fix it.

Comment: @MivaScott Good point too. I added it permanently to the main post, thank you.

Comment: The Replicate Magic Item infusion can be used to replicate common magic items not listed on the table, of which the Pot of Awakening is a part, but your point still stands. Thank you for the link at the end btw!

Comment: @JThompson Thanks for pointing that out too, I overlooked it, and removed that part of the bullet. Glad that the link was useful!

Comment: +1 for pointing out how much of a hassle it is in practice to keep track of all these creatures in combat. Even a single upcast Conjure Animals can easily double the length of time it takes to complete one round of combat. Unless you forget to create tokens/stat blocks for all of them well in advance, in which case you might as well give everyone a 30 minute snack break.